# Running Ansible playbooks with two different ansible_user accounts

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have the following playbook that runs a role on two inventories. win_domain is an inventory of domain-joined Windows targets while win_workgroup are non-domain joined targets.

```
---
- name: Windows Test
  hosts: win_domain, win_workgroup
  roles:
    - Windows_Test
```

The ansible_user used to run this playbook is a domain account that is not accessible to any targets in win_workgroup. Is there a way to run this playbook using two different ansible_users for each inventory?

Comment: You should be able to make `ansible_user` a group var.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Group Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/intro_inventory.html#group-variables) and set the connection type on a per group basis:

```
[win_domain]
domain__server_01 

[win_workgroup]
workgroup_server_01 

[win_domain:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh 
ansible_user=domain_user

[win_workgroup:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh 
ansible_user=localaccount
```